# It is possible to continuously update the UILabel text as user enter value in UITextField in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

In my application i have one `UILabel` and `UITextField`. Initially `UILabel` text in nil.
 As soon as user enter some text in `UITextField` my `UILabel` text also  Update.

Let say When user enter A in `UITextField` my `UILabel` immediately show A,  B in `UITextField` my `UILabel` show B and so on.

To achieve this behaviour  i used the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` function of `UITextFieldDelegate`. But it always behind one character. say `UITextField` text = qwerty my `UIlabel` text show qwert

Please help me so i can continuously update the `UILabel` text as user enter value in `UITextField`

here is my code

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    mylabel.text = textfield.text
   return true
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can register your textField for value change event:

```
[textField addTarget: self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and in `textFieldDidChange` function update your label:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange
{
    label.text = textField.text;
}
```

The function `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is needed more for taking desisions whether to allow upcoming change or not

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code to change the text:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{ 
   myLabel.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Nope, that will be 1 character behind, as the OP reports. Setting an action on the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

`In Swift`

Register your edit events

```
textfield.addTarget(self, action:"changeLabel", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)


func changeLabel(){
    myLabel.text=textfield.text
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code easy to understand :

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
   NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",yourtextfield.text,string];
   NSLog(@"%@",str);
   return YES;
}
```